# Show dialog in hooked method by xposed running in thread

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, xposed-framework

I try to show an AlertDialog within a hooked method with xposed.
The problem is that the method is running in a threads, and this thread is running in a thread, etc...

For example : 
Activity -> thread -> thread -> ... -> function

Is there a way to show my AlertDialog ? I have the Context, but since the hooked function is not in the main thread, it is useless.

EDIT (Some code) :

```
public class Xposed implements IXposedHookLoadPackage {
private Context ctx;
private Queue<String> queue = new LinkedList<>();

public void handleLoadPackage(final LoadPackageParam lpparam) throws Throwable {
    if (!lpparam.packageName.equals("xxx.xxx.xxx")) {
        return;
    }

    // Here I get the context from the static class extending Application
    findAndHookMethod("xxx.xxx.xxx", lpparam.classLoader, "attachBaseContext", Context.class, new XC_MethodHook() {
        @Override
        protected void afterHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
            XposedBridge.log("context modified");
            ctx = (Context) param.args[0];
        }
    });

    findAndHookMethod("com.xxx.xxx.xxx", lpparam.classLoader, "e", "com.xxx.xxx.xxx", String.class, new XC_MethodHook() {
        @Override
        protected void afterHookedMethod(final MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
            if (!(param.args[1]).equals("xxxxxxxxxxxxxx")) {
                return ;
            }

            XposedBridge.log("New element detected detected");
            Object param = param.args[0];
            Object info = callMethod(param, "q");

            // Here, I want to show my alertdialog
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE) {

                    }
                }
            };

            // I get the classic error like what I can't modify the ui
            // in a thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure ?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
                    .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener)
                    .show();
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always keep a reference of the current Activity ([android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html#newActivity%28java.lang.Class%3C?%3E,%20android.content.Context,%20android.os.IBinder,%20android.app.Application,%20android.content.Intent,%20android.content.pm.ActivityInfo,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29)). It goes something like this:

```
Class<?> instrumentation = XposedHelpers.findClass(
                "android.app.Instrumentation", lpparam.classLoader);

Method method = instrumentation.getMethod("newActivity",
                 ClassLoader.class, String.class, Intent.class);

XposedBridge.hookMethod(method, iHook);
```

In this case the ihook would be a hook of yours that just stores the current Activity statically so you can invoke the runOnUiThread from wherever you are:

```
public class ActivityHook extends XC_MethodHook{

    /* Assure latest read of write */
    private static volatile Activity _currentActivity = null;

    public static Activity getCurrentActivity() {
        return _currentActivity;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object afterHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param)
            throws Throwable {
        _currentActivity = (Activity) param.getResult();
    }
}
```

Then you will be able to do from anywhere:

```
ActivityHook.getCurrentActivity().runOnUiThread(...);
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! It's exactly what i wanted !
Just one thing, the ActivityHook does not extends XC_MethodReplacement but XC_MethodHook, the function is not the same and in the function, you have to cast the parameter : 
`protected void afterHookedMethod(XC_MethodHook.MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
        currentActivity = (Activity) param.getResult();
    }`

In any case, thanks again !!!

Comment: Sry, I didnt compile this code, wrote it directly here. Will make your changes :) Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have access to an activity you could get the main looper and then post ui related tasks.

Note: When you need to get the current applications context in an xposed module you don't need to hook anything like `attachBaseContext`. The xposed api provides a helper method for obtaining the current applications context `AndroidAppHelper.currentApplication()`.

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Do ui related stuff in here
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AndroidAppHelper.currentApplication());
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure ?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
                .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener)
                .show();
    }
});
```

`Looper.getMainLooper()` documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html#getMainLooper()

`Handler.post` documentation: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#post(java.lang.Runnable)

`AndroidAppHelper.currentApplication()` Source code:
https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/blob/art/src/android/app/AndroidAppHelper.java#L143-L145

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have the following exception with your code : `android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application`

Comment: P.S : I don't have any activity in my xposed application. I just want to show an alertdialog and a toast in the application I hook.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `runOnUiThread(runnable)` method to do this if you are running this code in an activity or a fragment.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't, since I have not the instance of the Activity. If I can get the instance of the activity, i can use the runOnUiThread function

Comment: Post some code so we know where exactly are you trying to access the main thread

Comment: If you are getting the context from an activity and not the applicationContext then you cast the context object to activity object and call the `runOnUiThread` method on that.