# Is there a way to develop an app that draws over a portion of the screen, in order to block ghost/phantom touches?

Tags: android-4.4-kitkat

*HTC Desire 510, Android 4.4.2 KitKat Rooted by SuperSU, with Xposed Framework.*

I understand there are ways to create an app that draws over other apps, but I haven't seen an app that draws over only part of the screen.

Here's some background on my problem.

1. One day, my phone decided to have a ghost touch problem
2. I enabled the "Show Touches" in the developer options and i saw that all of 
    the touches were coming from the top right of the screen.
3. I then enable the "show pointer location", or something like that, and i saw 
    that all of the touches were happening within X: 370-380.

I've seen some apps that I've used that draw over, do block the touches onto the current open app, so I was wondering if I could have an app block that area down to around a third of the screen. If I need to just send in my phone, I would, but I rooted it. I think i can un-root it but that for a different thread. I would try to open the phone by myself, but I'd probably break it. So I'm trying to live with it and work around it. If you need more information, just ask below.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure how generic this is in the case of games but in theory you could intercept all touch events for any given activity and cancel those that occur within the given coordinates.

Try to intercept the [dispatchTouchEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)) method of Activity. Note that it receives a [MotionEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) which contains the touch coordinates. Match these coordinates against your range and, if it should be ignored, change the dispatchTouchEvent method [return](https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/blob/art/app/src/main/java/de/robv/android/xposed/XC_MethodHook.java#L96) to true (event consumed).

Since the `dispatchTouchEvent` method can be overridden, you might need to check if this method is declared in any given Activity. Otherwise your hook might not work. To intercept new Activities, check [this stackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32102901/show-dialog-in-hooked-method-by-xposed-running-in-thread/32606434#32606434). In its `afterHookedMethod` method, just check if the method is declared via [param.this.getClass().getDeclaredMethods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods()) (or make it more specific by using `getDeclaredMethod`). If defined hook it the same way you hooked the `dispatchTouchEvent` for the Activity class.

N.B: Make sure you dont hook the same method multiple times.